# The sequence " " already exist (doctrine:schema:update) symfony2.8

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem upgrading my database with doctrine and I didn't found any solution yet. 
I followed the fosUserBundle tutorial on symfony and all worked well until final step 7.

```
Now that the bundle is configured, the last thing you need to do is update your database schema 
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I have this error :

```
 The sequence 'julien.carrosserie_id_seq' already exists.
```

As I saw on internet it seems to be a relation between tables problem but i'm not exprimented enough to proper identify the source of the problem.
Carrosserie (which means sheet metal) is contained in 1 annonce (announce) here are my both entities :

[image]

[image: class Annonce]

[image: error]

--force option doens't solve the problem either. 
If you need any others informations do not hesitate, thanks for the time you spent reading my post.

Comment: It looks like you have `sequenceName="carrosserie_id_seq"` in more than one entity. Do you have any other entities?

Comment: I do have 32 entities but I looked on them all and haven't any other sequence named as the carrosserie's one